# Spawn flask app, make a request, and kill it in same script (run flask in background from python script)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to write some integration test for my flask-app thus I want to write a script which spawns the app, make a request, kill the app.

The issue seems to be to run flask in background (I'm running windows 11), right now I have my `app.py` which contains a simple app:

```py
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.json.ensure_ascii = False


@app.route('/predict', methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    return {"hello": "world"}

@app.route('/health', methods=["GET"])
def health():
    return "OK"
```

and `test.py` which should spawn the app, make a request, and kill it.

I have tried the following in `test.py`

```py
# using "pythonw"

import os
import subprocess
command = "pythonw -m flask --app app run --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000"
command_list = command.split()
proc = subprocess.Popen(command_list)
print(proc.pid) #prints id but requests failed. Seems like the process is killed
```

```py
# using "python"

import os
import subprocess
command = "python -m flask --app app run --host=127.0.0.1 --port=8000"
command_list = command.split()
proc = subprocess.Popen(command_list)
print(proc.pid) #prints id but does not run in background. Requests from another script works
```

I have tried various arguments in `Popen` but nothing seems to work.
Note, since I'm running windows `gunicorn` cannot be used.

I don't know if I just have to spin the flask-server up in a docker container, but I think it's kinda overkill.